# How to get both Null value data and empty string data onto a gridview from a single dropdown selected value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview, dataset

How can I get both Null value data and empty string data onto a gridview from a single dropdown selected value. I've a condition where I've to show pending data in which one of the database column will be either NULL or empty string. How can I show both together in a single dropdown selected index.

This is the code which I've done.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" Height="26px" Width="133px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStatus_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Accept">Accepted</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Reject">Rejected</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="">Pending</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

But this helps be fetch only those data which has empty strings.

In the below codebehind I just fetch data from database by the dropdownlist selected value.

```
protected void ddlStatus_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Jilu1TableAdapters.tbl_Jr_BOMTableAdapter ds;
    ds = new Jilu1TableAdapters.tbl_Jr_BOMTableAdapter();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = ds.GetStatus(ddlStatus.SelectedValue);

    gvStatus.DataSource = dt;
    gvStatus.DataBind();
}
```

Query behind GetStatus is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ddlState, ddlDistrict, ddlCluster, ddlSiteID, txtSiteName, Status, Dispatch
FROM tbl_Jr_BOM
WHERE (Status = @Status)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what code you have written in GetStatus function ?

Comment: if  @Status == "" then change the query to - SELECT DISTINCT ddlState, ddlDistrict, ddlCluster, ddlSiteID, txtSiteName, Status, Dispatch
FROM            tbl_Jr_BOM
WHERE     (Status  is null or Status = @Status)

Comment: How the syntax would be?? Because this is what I wanted.

Comment: How are you calling this query ? Are you using stored prcedure or inline query? Show me your code then i will provide syntax accordingly

Comment: what is ur expected result...